# zip multiple files on server and echo back zip file

Tags: php, jquery

Consider a site which allows user to store files (pdf, docx, jpeg, png, gif only). Part of the html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="../folder/lola.doc" target="_blank">lola.doc</a></li>
    <li><a href="../folder/lola.pdf" target="_blank">lola.pdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="../folder/lola.jpeg" target="_blank">lola.jpeg</a></li>
    <li><a href="../folder/lola.docx" target="_blank">lola.docx</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on any of the above, the file either opens or a save dialpg appears. This is fine.

Now I want user to be able to select some of these files (which are on the server). The files will be zipped and echo back to user with a prompt to save. I cannot use above, so I have this option:

html:

```
<select class="multiple_select " multiple>
    <option value="../folder/lola.doc">lola.doc</option>
    <option value="../folder/lola.pdf">lola.pdf</option>
    <option value="../folder/lola.jpeg">lola.jpeg</option>
    <option value="../folder/lola.docx">lola.docx</option>
</select>
<button id="btn" type="button">Download</button>
```

js:

```
js:

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var options_selected = $('select').find('option:selected');
    options_selected_le = options_selected.length;
    var i;
    var options_selected_arr = [];
    var options_names_arr = [];
    for (i=0; i<options_selected_le; i++) {
        options_selected_arr.push(options_selected.eq(i).val());
        options_names_arr.push(options_selected.eq(i).text());
    }

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('zipname', zipname);
    fd.append('options_selected_arr', JSON.stringify(options_selected_arr));
    fd.append('options_names_arr', JSON.stringify(options_names_arr));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'download_multiple_files.php', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Download", "yes"); 
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response); //I am sure this is wrong
            // Do I need js to handle zip file here. I guess php should automatically do this
        }
    }); 
});

<?php
  session_start();
  require 'server_conn.php'; // for connection and holds test_input function
  // do some security checks ...

  $zipname = 'file.zip';
  $arr = json_decode($_POST['options_selected_arr']);
  $file_arr = [];
  foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    array_push($files_arr, test_input($obj));
  }  

  $arr = json_decode($_POST['options_names_arr']);
  $files_names_arr = [];
  foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    array_push($files_names_arr, test_input($obj));
  }

  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
  for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    $zip->addFile($file_arr[$i], $files_names_arr[$i]);
  }  
  $zip->close();

  header('Content-Type: application/zip');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
  readfile($zipname);
  unlink($zipname);   
?>
```

Response from server is giberish and there is no error indication. I suspect my php is defective.

Comment: You're not doing any checks on the responses to the ZipArchive calls.  You might see see one or more of them failing.  Also, did you check that your server response is not in fact an error page rather than a zip file?  F12 in Chrome, network tab, look at response.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using 2 methods:
Method 1:
JSZip without php (Each select option already contains file path as value)
The advantage of this method: It does not store the new zip file on the server, so storage is not a problem.
I believe using blob will also allow ziping large files, max size I don't know.
To use this method, one needs to download Filesaver, jszip and jszip utility and add following lines to the html doc body

```
    <script src="../js/lib/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

The js script makes use of Promisejs, which I haven't studied before (but will now do). Below is the js:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    function urlToPromise(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    var options_selected = $('select').find('option:selected');
    options_selected_le = options_selected.length;

    var zipname = 'file.zip';

    var Promise = window.Promise;
    if (!Promise) {
        Promise = JSZip.external.Promise;
    }

    var i;
    var zip = new JSZip();
    for (i=0; i<options_selected_le; i++) {
        var url = options_selected.eq(i).val();
        var filename = options_selected.eq(i).text();
        zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});
    }

    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function callback(blob) {
        //see FileSaver.js
        saveAs(blob, zipname);
        //alert('success'); 
    }, function (e) {
        alert('Error zipping file(s). Retry');
    }); 
});
```

Method 2:
Using js and PHP:
First create a folder on the server to hold the zip file, I name the folder 'archive'
This is why I may not vote for this method.
New js:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var options_selected = $('select').find('option:selected');
    options_selected_le = options_selected.length;

    var zipname = 'file.zip';       
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('zipname', zipname);
    fd.append('options_selected_arr', JSON.stringify(options_selected_arr));
    fd.append('options_names_arr', JSON.stringify(options_names_arr));

    $.ajax ({
        url: 'download_multiple_files.php', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            window.location = response;
        }
    });
});
```

New php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // connect to server, scan input data and do some security checks ...

  $zipname = 'file.zip';
  $arr = json_decode($_POST['options_selected_arr']);
  $file_arr = [];
  foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    array_push($files_arr, test_input($obj));
  }  

  $arr = json_decode($_POST['options_names_arr']);
  $files_names_arr = [];
  foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    array_push($files_names_arr, test_input($obj));
  }

  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $path = '/archive/'.$zipname;
  if ($zip->open($path, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    echo 'Cannot zip files'; die;
  }

  $c = count($file_arr);
  for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    $zip->addFile($file_arr[$i], $files_names_arr[$i]);
  }

  $zip->close();
  echo $path;
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This will force save dialog to appear. Two pending challenges I have for this method are:
Prevent a new window to open
The save dialog appears with download as file name but without extension .zip. So user should type .zip along with the name. I would prefer the computed zip filename to appear in the save dialog